# How to click on a div using page_objects gem?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

Using page_objects gem, Cucumber and Watir-Webdriver. I have a link/button that I want to click on. In IRB I can click on it via the div as such:

```
b.div(:text, "Verify your membership").click
```

The HTML:

```
div class="verification-header button -gray -browse btn-verify" style="top: 0px;">
  Verify your membership
</div>
```

In my page object I have:

```
  div(:membership, :text => "Verify your membership")
```

And I call it as such:

```
membership
```

But the link/button isn't clicked. So the question is how to click a link/button that is a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Div elements do not usually need to be clicked, which is why the page object accessor creates a `membership` method to return the div text rather than click it.

To click it, you can directly call the `click` method:

```
membership_element.click
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! I was calling .click on 'membership' but didn't realize I had to use 'membership_element'.